# How to write a Tax Query that matches all terms in an array?

Tags: tax-query

I'm creating a product filter, and I've been struggling trying to figure out how to get this query to work properly. I need to be able to feed this query an array of terms (woocommerce product attributes), and I need it to return the products that have **all** of the terms provided.

So far, it seems to return the products that have any of the terms. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the arguments that I have so far:

```
 $selectedOptions = array('test-attribute', 'test3');

 $args=array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query'           => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_filterable-attribute',
            'terms'         => $selectedOptions,
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
```

And Here is my loop if it matters:

```
$my_query = null;   
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) { 
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
    woocommerce_product_subcategories();
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; 
  woocommerce_product_loop_end();
  }
  wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe changing your operator to 'AND' like below will work:

```
$selectedOptions = array('test-attribute', 'test3');

$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query'           => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'pa_filterable-attribute',
            'terms'         => $selectedOptions,
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'operator'      => 'AND'
        )
    )
);
```